# Variance of Guassian Products

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution

Suppose I have to vectors $w$ and $x$, each of size $[512,1]$. Each element of $w$ and $x$ is an i.i.d sample from a Guassian Distibution with mean 0 and variance 1. So $x_i$ and $w_i$ follow  $N(0,1)$

Let $y=w^Tx$  be my vector of interest. Then the question is what is the variance of $y$?

So $y=\sum w_ix_i$

$Var(y)=\sum Var(w_ix_i)$

I do not know how to take it forward from here....

Comment: The next step is to write the Var operator as an expectation ($Var(X) = E[(X-E[X])^2]$). Then, note that if $A$ and $B$ are independent, then $E[AB]=E[A]E[B]$

Comment: Okay so we have $Var(X)=E((AB)^2)$. Then what?

Comment: You assume A and B are independent. So also $A^2$ and $B^2$.

Comment: Ok so I then get $Var(y)=\sum 1*1=n$ . Which is 512 in this case.  Suppose W was a $512*512$ matrix. Then $y$ would be a vector where each entry has variance 512. So what would the total variance of vector $y$ be?